# The work and reversibility of an adiabadically stretched band

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, work, reversibility, adiabatic

I currently working on [this](https://emineter.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/problems-on-statistical-mechanics.pdf). More specifically I have a question about Problem 2.8 (solution on page 34 and exercise on page 25 of the pdf). I have 4 questions
1.
In the solution for b) the author says that $U$ is only a function of $T$ because $\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial L}\bigg)_T=0$. I assume the author talks here about displaying the internal energy with the 3 state variables $J,L,T$. But he does not show why
$$
\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial J}\bigg)_{L,T}=T\bigg(\frac{\partial S}{\partial J}\bigg)_{T,L}+J\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial J}\bigg)_{T,L}
$$
would be 0.

 Or maybe the author is refering do the formula $dE=TdS+JdL$ for the internal Energy. But I dont quite get why the internal energy should only be a function of T.
2. In the next line he says $dU=C_LdT$. Why is that true? I assume that he has used the first law $dU=\delta Q-\delta W$ and $\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T}\bigg)_L=C_L$ for that. But I thought that the work here is not $0$ since the band is being stretched which needs some work to be done. 
3. During the integration (first formula on page 35 of the pdf) $C_L$ is assumed to be constant. But I thought that it is only constant if the length stays the same. But here the band gets stretched. So I thought $C_L$ would also have to be integrated over
4. this is about the solution for c) and maybe lead to the same answer as the one for 3. I think. In c) its said that no work is being done and that the process is irreversible. I would have thought that work is being done, only negative. Now does not gain, but lose energy through mechanical deformation. And why is the stretching said to be reversible but not the unstretching ? I mean reversing the unstretching would be stretching. And this is possible as it was done before

Answer (score 0):

U is a function of only two state variables, in this case S and L or T and L.  But, just as the internal energy of an ideal gas is not a function of V, for this elastic material, the internal energy is not a function of L.

If U is a function only of T, then $$dU=\left(\frac{d U}{d T}\right)dT=C_vdT$$

U being dependent only on T (and not J or L) implies that $$J-T\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial T}\right)_L=0$$which implies that the tension J is proportional to T at constant L.  This would have to be an experimental observation of the band behavior.  It would be analogous to the pressure being proportional to the temperature at constant volume for an ideal gas.

Comment: Why do you assume that $C_v=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$?

Comment: That is the definition of Cv.